# How can I create my own user-code authentication on firebase in android app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to build android application uses firebase server, I would like to add an authentication to the application, I have searched a lot in the internet, all firebase authentication examples are using google/email/..

But none is using own authentication, what I want to do is:

1. I will initialize all users data in firebase with unique "id" for each user (no sign up/registration from user)
2. I will give each user his private unique "id" I initialized for him
3. User will enter in the application the "id" I gave him - app should check if there is any user with this "id" or not and behave accordingly.

I did the first 2 steps, I have no idea of how to do the third one.

I know how to initialize firebase and iterate over user, but this will be enough ?

How can I gain such an authentication ?

Any help is appreciated

Please forgive my lack of knowledge.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using token based authentication in firebase?

Comment: Why don't you look at the anonymous authentication in Firebase, it will handle all that logic for you.

Comment: @ma.gr No, this will force me to have another server to manage tokens, right ?

Comment: @sketchthat, If I understood the anonymous correctly, it does not give me the option to authenticate use specific "id", it give him the option to sign in anonymously. Thanks

Comment: How are you sending each id to user's app?

Comment: @ma.gr, sorry for late response, I'm going to give them the code by hand on a paper.